How to see character
Say this character's name. Are you able to put her in blender?

I'm not quite sure what you are talking about, but it sounds like you want to download and use the character in the image's background. Her name is Ellie, and the character is from the Sprite Fright open movie by Blender Foundation. You can download the character file here: https://studio.blender.org/characters/ellie/v1/
EDIT: To download the file, click on the button that looks like it has three dots up and down. The Download button should be in the menu that pops up. I would suggest reading the description and warning (which is in yellow box). It might also be a good idea to read through the comments if you have problems opening the file and using it.
